# Add Two Bridged Interfaces on Ubuntu for KVM

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I have ran the following;

```
sudo /usr/sbin/brctl addbr br0
sudo /usr/sbin/brctl  addif br0 eth0
```

And added the following to /etc/network/interfaces;

```
auto br0 # for XPProxx86 KVM
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_maxwait 0
  bridge_fd 0
```

This works perfectly; My XP VM can see the LAN and be reached via the LAN on my laptop. I have another VM I want to do the same with; so I am running two fully reachable VMs on my laptop. I have ran;

```
sudo /usr/sbin/brctl addbr br1
```

But then I get the following error;

```
sudo /usr/sbin/brctl  addif br1 eth0
device br1 already exists; can't create bridge with the same name
```

Is it not possible to have two VMs on my laptop (which only has one NIC) with access to the local network and be individually accessible from other LAN hosts? I don't want the to be NAT'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show us `brtctl show`

You can have more bridges, but you don`t need one bridge for each VM!
my interfaces (with serving 9 VMs):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.2
        dns-search dmz.example.com
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        bridge_stp off
```

Comment: Hi ThorstenS, yes that is exactly the mistake I have made. I have given each VM their own MAC addresses, thats all that matter, I see know they can share the same bridge adapter.